# Get exact time of the file added to the folder

Tags: macos, shell, macos-high-sierra

Is there a way to find out "Time added" of the file to the folder?

On macOs you can arrange files by **day** added, but is there a way to do it in command line for the exact **time** added?

I tried the `find` `-ctime -cmin -amin -mmin` etc. but they only display Creation/Access/Modification time.

Update: 
For e.g.: I take photograph on 1st Dec, I put it into the folder on 2nd Dec. Creation Date would be 1st Dec, but I would need to find out when and at what time exactly I added the image into the directory.

On macOS you can  arrange by Date Added >>> which consequently displays the day when it was added, even the Creation/Modification/Access date is different. Though, it will divide files only into couple of categories: Today, Yesterday, 7 Days Ago, Previous 30 days. Is there anything equivalent in comand line, so it would be possible to be more precise when figuring out when it was added? not to limit yourself to only a few categories?

[image: arrange files by Date Added]

Comment: What do you mean with "time added"? Do you mean creation time?

Comment: For e.g.: I take photograph on 1st Dec, I put it into the folder on 2nd Dec. Creation Date would be 1st Dec, but I would need to find out when and at what time exactly I added the image into the directory.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4

Comment: The problem is that `stat` does not show the birth time, but you can extract it with debugfs. Have a look at this website, it explains how to extract the information: http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `mdls` tool in order to find "Date Added" ( `kMDItemDateAdded` ).

To find the **Date Added** of a single file:

```
mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded image1.png
```

**Output**:

```
kMDItemDateAdded                   = 2018-12-13 06:28:36 +0000
```

If you want to check all files in a directory you could do something such as:

```
for i in * ; do 
    da=$(mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded "$i" | awk -F= '{print $2}') 
    printf "%-25s <-- Date Added --> %-20s\n" "${i:0:24}" "$da"
done
```

**Output**:

```
image1.png      <-- Date Added -->  2018-12-12 07:26:58 +0000
image2.png      <-- Date Added -->  2018-12-11 10:26:03 +0000
image3.png      <-- Date Added -->  2018-12-13 22:16:30 +0000
```

Comment: You can use `mdls -name kMDItemDateAdded` instead of grepping.